# WPF Cursor on a partially transparent image

Tags: wpf, transparency, wpf-4.0, mouse-cursor

I have a png that contains transparent regions and I set it to the image tag.

How am I able to set the cursor to a hand when it is over an opaque part of the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you will need to look at the bitmap itself.  WPF's hit testing mechanism considers any pixel painted ith a "transparent" brush to still be clickable even though invisible.  This is normally a good thing but gets in the way of what you're trying to do.  Because a .png paints with the transparent brush, the entire .png is considerd as painted when doing hit testing.

What you need to do in your `MouseMove` event handler is:

1. Go ahead and invoke hit testing the normal way.
2. For each `HitTestResult` you get back, check to see if it is an `Image` and if so, whether a transparent pixel is under the mouse
3. When you get a hit on a non-image or a non-transparent pixel of an image, stop.
4. Decide on a `Cursor` value based on what the mouse is over

To determine whether a the mouse is over a transparent pixel of an image:

1. Get the mouse position relative to the image (`e.GetPosition(image)`)
2. If you're using stretching you must back-compute the stretch at this point to get a bitmap index
3. Use `BitmapSource.CopyPixels` to copy a 1-pixel rectangle into an array (ie. only the single pixel the mouse is over)
4. Check the pixel value that was retrieved to see if it is a transparent pixel