# WPF - All images triggering mouse-based events rather than the single desired image

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a bit of a problem with a WPF application that I can't quite figure out. My interface consists of 5 overlapping transparent images. All images are of the same size with different elements of the interface being visible through each of the images. My problem is that I only want to be able to interact with the topmost image (the very last one defined in the grid). I've linked the MouseLeftButtonUp, MouseRightButtonUp, MouseEnter and MouseLeave event handlers to the topmost image only, but for some reason when I run the application and interact with any of the other images (through the transparent parts of the topmost image) they also trigger said events.
Does anyone happen to know why this is and how I can fix it?

Edit: Here's a link to a simplified project file:

[MouseProblem project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vbqbnybea8gs79/MouseProblem.zip?dl=0)

Edit: I've attached the corresponding images below (Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post more than 2 links):

Note: The only time I want an event to be triggered is when the mouse enters, clicks or leaves the smallest, centermost circle (Inner_Button).

[The 5 interface elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hor6X.png)

My Grid is set up as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Image 
        x:Name="Frame"
        Margin="5"
        Source="Interface/Frame.png"
        Height="250"
        Width="250"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        />

    <Image 
        x:Name="Outer_Indicator"
        Margin="5"
        Source="Interface/Outer_Idle.png"
        Height="250"
        Width="250"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        />

    <Image 
        x:Name="Mouse_Indicator"
        Margin="5"
        Source="Interface/Mouse_Out.png"
        Height="250"
        Width="250"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        />

    <Image 
        x:Name="_Inner_Indicator"
        Margin="5"
        Source="Interface/Inner_Idle.png"
        Height="250"
        Width="250"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform
                x:Name="Interface_Rotation"
                Angle="0"
                />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

    <Image 
        x:Name="Inner_Button"
        Margin="5"
        Source="Interface/Inner_Button.png"
        Height="250"
        Width="250"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Cursor="Hand"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="leftClick"
        MouseRightButtonUp="rightClick"
        MouseEnter="mouseEnter"
        MouseLeave="mouseLeave"
        />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you possibly share the images in question? Or at least the topmost one? I failed to reproduce your issue with sample image I've created...

Comment: There you go, I had to combine the 5 elements into one image with the left side being the bottommost image and the right being the topmost with everything else in order inbetween.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly it's not that mouse events are triggered for all images (you're not subscribing to any events on images other than the top one) - I was not able to reproduce such behavior. Judging from the images you've provided I think your issue is that mouse events are triggered when the mouse is over any part of the top image, but you expect them to be triggered only when the mouse is over a non-transparent part of the image.

Unfortunately such feature is not available in *WPF* out-of-the-box. Now there are two main approaches that you can take.

## Approach I

Check in each mouse event handler whether the mouse is over a non-transparent pixel of the image and do your logic only then (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250965/wpf-cursor-on-a-partially-transparent-image) for reference). This might be tricky though, especially when the image is displayed not in it's original size.

## Approach II

Use the `Image.Clip` property supplied with appropriate geometry to tell the framework which parts of the `Image` are subject for hit-testing.

Personally in your case I'd go with the second approach since the size of the `Image` control is constant (and clip geometry does not automatically scale to the size of the control) and the image content is basically a circle. Here's what I think should get you the result you're after:

```
<Image x:Name="Inner_Button" (...)>
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="125,125" RadiusX="53" RadiusY="53" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Note though that the supplied geometry will not match your image perfectly. At least it did not at my side - there were few transparent pixels that still triggered mouse events, but it was hardly noticeable.

If you're after a perfect solution though you could switch from using images to using shapes, but depending on the complexity of your images it might prove to be an exhausting exercise...

Comment: I originally thought the same thing, however the transparent parts of the image aren't triggering the events, only the non transparent parts, ie. the blue circle in the centre and the surrounding rings. The mouse detection is behaving as it should, the only problem is that the underlying images are also being detected, I can't get the cursor to the centre circle (meant to be the only functional button) without moving over the outer rings of which are triggering the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events. If that makes sense.

Comment: I find it peculiar because I seem to get different results. Could you specify what version of the framework are you using? Also, I've got two questions. 1. What's the harm in the other images triggering mouse events since you do not subscribe to them (you probably ignore these events triggered by windows, user controls etc.)? 2. Did you try setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the images you do not want to trigger mouse events?

Comment: I believe I'm using the 4.5.2 framework, although it could be newer, I'm not near my computer at the moment so I can't verify that. It doesn't do any harm, but visual aspects of the interface (ie the colour of certain parts of the interface) are changed on MouseEnter and MouseLeave and because of the several rings in the way of the central button the interface somewhat flickers and is rather annoying. If it wasn't bothering me I wouldn't have asked the question. I did also try changing the IsHitTestVisible to false for each of the images to no success.

Comment: @MichaelClarke Could you perhaps create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Preferably a zipped project reproducing your issue? I've tried several tricks yet the issue does not occur at my side - the top image is triggering mouse events regardless of whether the cursor is over a transparent or non-transparent part of the image, and other images do not trigger any mouse events...

Comment: There you go, It's not the whole project as I am not able to share that, but it does contain the issue I've been having.

Comment: Turns out the game-changing difference is that you set `AllowTransparency="True"` on your window whereas I did not. However, I've just confirmed that the second approach described should still work for you (and I believe the first one also, but I didn't check that). If you want me to elaborate on what's exactly going on let me know.